# How to stop elements moving when resizing the broswer

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I have a project to finish it's to make a similar page as wikipedia, however, I am about to give up, just when I thought I finally wrote the code and tried to revise the browse / move it from the corner either every element follows the browser movement or it messes everything up, After many googling I even tried the WRAPPER thing as it is given in the code , please help

jsfiddle.net/gpe4jn0k    here is the code

Comment: Have you tried `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: It was connected to css and responsible design if anyone is going to have the same problem read about it.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design